# How to get the 3 digit currency code from locale Globalize

Tags: angular, typescript, globalize, javascript-globalize

I'm trying to use globalize 1.x in my angular project.I want to know whether there is any way to get the 3 digit currency code from the locale .For example if the locale is en-us ,how can i get USD from it .My scenario is i want to use Globalize.currencyFormatter but this method accepts only ISO 3 digit cuurency format .[Globalize](https://github.com/globalizejs/globalize#currency-module)

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out? If so, care to share your answer?